# Swapping/Hiding/Toggling Memoized component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

I have been trying to toggle the visibility of a rather expensive component in my SPA using the React.memo() API. I am using Context Consumer and Provider for State management as the App is fairly small.
I need to show/hide the expensive component on a state change and am trying to prevent any re renders.
Basically the App has two tabs Tab1 and tab 2 where I need to show the respective tabs on a button click. I am able to achieve that but the components re-rendering.
Currently the Tabs do not re render if memoized and are shown together. However, trying to control the visibility breaks memoization :(
Could someone please help/ guide me implementing memoization to cache the components and show when required without a re-render?

Comment: If you are using `React.memo` I assume you are using function components? Why not make use of the more targeted memoization functions like `React.useMemo` and just store the parts of the component that are effecting your performance. You can then toggle visibility / view layout and keep these sections memoized.

Comment: I can try that. Thank you. Meanwhile can you help me understand why it doesn't work with React.memo?

Comment: So I can think 1 of 2 things possibly happening here since no code has been provided: A) When you toggle the visibility of the component you are removing it from the render tree and all the memoized data is destroyed. When remounting the component when it is shown again all the logic must be recomputed. B) React.memo is an all or nothing fix, which is why it is recommended to use the more targeted hooks when using function components. With React.memo if any of the props change (reference comparison) then the component will rerender and I assume that you must change a prop to toggle visibility

Comment: So it should be fair to assume that the React.memo api memoizes the component only of the very preceeding render cycle? If I have three render cycles 1,2,3 and component A isn't in render cycle 2 for it's invisible (removed from render tree) then render cycle 3 has no cached component A. Right?

Comment: Yes, React.memo only keeps the memoized data while the component exists in the tree. If you conditionally render the component `{ condition && <ComponentA /> }` (or similar) then you will be removing the component from the tree and removing the data.

Comment: Ok I tried useMemo() but as expected it caches the component with the state provided at that time. Let's say I do useMemo(Tab1) and then some child of Tab1 undergoes state change where only that child rebuilds and not Tab1 as whole. Now if I toggle tabs, Tab1 will not rebuild for it's memoized but will have the children with old state. How could I circumvent that in an efficient way? Adding useMemo to each child doesn't seem very elegant to me :/