# Child component is memoized with useMemo in the parent, how to make child component signal the parent to re-compute the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

I'm in a situation just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908453/swapping-hiding-toggling-memoized-component) where I need to toggle between two components, both components can get significantly heavy so I memoized them.

Following the first comment from the link above, I'm using the `useMemo()` hook in the parent of both components so I can show/hide a particular component:

```js
function myComponent() {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('Books');

  const MemoizedBooks = useMemo(() => <Books />, []);
  const MemoizedRequests = useMemo(() => <Requests />, []);
  
  return (
      <div>{activeTab === 'Books' ? MemoizedBooks : MemoizedRequests}</div>
  )
}
```

#### The problem/question

If the `<Books/>` component updates itself for instance, how will the parent `myComponent` know of this update and then update `memoizedBooks`?

Comment: on the other hand, I'm thinking that the parent doesn't need to be aware of these updates because the child component re-rendering will cause the parent to update itself?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `<Books />` is not a component itself, it's a lightweight JSX element that tells React to render the actual component. You did not memoise anything heavy. And `myComponent` does not need to update/re-render if any state inside the `Books` component changes.

Comment: @giorgimoniava Ah, [interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60453845/1048572)! But in the example you linked, there is some actual `// The rest of your rendering logic` and a dependency for the `useMemo` hook. There's neither in the OP's code.